# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am writing a program that uses *urllib2* to download CSV data from an http site. The program works fine when run within Python, however I am also trying to use *argparse* to be able to enter the url from the command line.

I get the following error when I run it:

```
File "urlcsv.py", line 51, in downloadData
    return urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 396, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'get_type'
```

I guess this is part of the *urllib2* library because it is not code that I have written.
Has anybody else encountered similar problems with either the *argparse* or *urllib2* modules?

The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("url")


def main():
    """Runs when the program is opened"""

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args is False:
        SystemExit
    try:
        csvData = downloadData(args)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        print 'Please try a different URL'
        raise
    else:
        LOG_FILENAME = 'errors.log'
        logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                            level=logging.DEBUG,
                            )
        logging.getLogger('assignment2')
        personData = processData(csvData)
        ID = int(raw_input("Enter a user ID: "))
        if ID <= 0:
            raise Exception('Program exited, value <= 0')
        else:
            displayPerson(ID)
            main()

def downloadData(url):

    return urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: The stack trace is of course indicating a problem in the `urllib2` module, from the paths being given.

Comment: Show us the code you have written, and the input you are giving.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't include the line with the error.   What do you have `req` set to?

Comment: @tristan the line `protocol = req.get_type()` is part of the urllib2 module in the Python standard library; it is not code that I have written, it is code that is called by `urllib2.urlopen(url)`

Comment: But you haven't included the line in your example of where you set `protocol=req.get_type()`, which means you still need to "post the code," so to speak.  I don't know where you're expecting req to exist, because there's not a member method `urllib2.req`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're parsing command line arguments into `args`, which is a `Namespace` with attributes set to the parsed arguments.  But you're passing this entire namespace to `downloadData`, rather than just the url.  This namespace is then passed to `urlopen`, which doesn't know what to do with it.  Instead, call `downloadData(args.url)`.

Answer (score 13):

Long story short.

Arguments in object returned from `parser.parse_args()` should be accessed via properties rather than via `[]` syntax.

#### Wrong

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args['method']
```

#### Correct

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args.method
```

Comment: What if the arg name contains special character? For example instead of "method", I use "<method>". 

But then "args.<method>" will be obviously invalid.

Comment: @gye don't use special characters in your argument names?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem due to a whitespace before the option sting.

Answer (score 1):

May be helpful for others in future.

If you are using `metavar` or `dest` make sure you understand what these arguments are for.

In short:

- `meta_var` is something to do with the help message which is printed
- `dest` is the name of the attribute which will be set (name of attribute which is created to store your command line argument when parsed)