# Does clone experiment work on sklearn functions?

Tags: trains, clearml

I'm trying to run a script and I'm constantly getting this while cloning experiment in allegro.ai
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'get'
Can anybody help?

Comment: Please refer to this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422883/attributeerror-namespace-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422883/attributeerror-namespace-object-has-no-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I'm part of the Allegro Trains Team :)

Where exactly are you getting the error ? Python or Web UI?

To clone a Task (experiment) from code this is what you can do:

```py
from trains import Task

my_cloned_task = Task.clone(source_task='aabbcc112233')
```

The `task_id` is the UID of the task (experiment) you want to clone. To get an experiment ID, go to the web UI , in the experiment info panel, to the right of the experiment name, press on the "ID" button and you will see the ID of the Task.